# Is there record of a pubilc RDS instance with strong password having been hacked?

Tags: passwords, databases, aws

I am auditing an AWS account and I found a public RDS instance, that is with public DNS, no Security Group IP connection filtering and in a public Subnet

However, the instance has a relatively strong password (12 characters, symbols, numbers, and lower case and capital letters)

Is there public record of a database like this having been hacked?

Now production queries made to it are done through SSL but is not a requirement, and I suppose this would be much harder but is there public record of a database like this having been hacked? (this time considering SSL)